# How do you find by id using the MongoDB Node driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm looking for the best way to find by id using the [MongoDB Node driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/).

I see that the `_id` field is an `ObjectId`, and so using a string for the id won't work. And I see that you [could use ObjectId](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/objectid/) as follows:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

exports.show = function(req, res) {
  var db = req.app.get('db');
  var id = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
  db.collection('posts').findOne({
    _id: id
  }, function(err, post) {
    res.status(200).json(post);
  });
};
```

But is there a best practice/more convenient way? I hadn't come across one in looking through the docs. Note: Mongoose has a [findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) method where you could just use the id string.

Answer (score 1):

The _id field is already indexed, and findByID implicitly searches for one document, hence, `findOne` where you'll pass options `{_id: id}` as you're already doing.

Comment: So you're saying that the way I'm doing it is the best practice?

Comment: Yes, findByID would be another function (i.e. redundant), and functions are expensive in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the major design consideration was to make native driver API similar to the mongo shell experience and keep it consistent all over the place (other drivers as well?). For this purpose you might want to keep API simple, yet powerful to cover all cases. So, to generalize, you have `find()` method and ["a db.collection.findOne() method as a special case of find() that returns a single document."](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/#query-behavior)