# Query a collection with an object id

Tags: mongodb

I have an tickets collection where i've a property which is stored an object id. i want to search the tickets collection with an object id that matches the property which is stored as an object id.

Comment: You can use `find()` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find by id using the MongoDB Node driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215298/how-do-you-find-by-id-using-the-mongodb-node-driver)